# Docker and Django manage.py

Tags: django, docker, manage.py

I'm trying to find a workflow with Docker and Django. Currently, I'm using the basic configuration from [the docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/).

I'd like to use `manage.py startapp` directly from the container to start a new app using:

```
docker-compose run web ./manage.py startapp myapp
```

But all the files created in the volume are owned by the root user and not by myself, so I can't edit them from the host.

My idea is to avoid installing all the requirements on my host machine but maybe I should not create app from the container?

One possible solution is to create a user and make it having the same UID/GID than my user on my host machine but it won't work if I try to use an other account on my host machine...

Any suggestion?

Comment: You should add a `USER xx` in your Dockerfile, xx being a non-privileged user, that you created before in your Dockerfile an extract from https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/ "with something like RUN groupadd -r postgres && useradd -r -g postgres postgres"

Comment: an example of Dockerfile with useradd and USER https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=1809831

Comment: It works because my user account on the host machine has the same UID/GID than the user created in the container. However, it won't work if I use another account on my host machine :/

Comment: You can uid gid as parameters for the Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

What worked best for me was avoiding (or minimizing) file creation inside the containers.

My Dockerfile would just copy the requirements.txt and install them;
and the container would access the app files through a mounted volume.

I pass the env var `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1` to the containers, so python does not create `*.pyc/*.pyo` files.

The few times I cannot avoid it (like, `./manage.py makemigrations`), I run `chown` afterwards. 
It's not ideal, but as this happens rarely for my case, I don't bother.